# NumPy array value error from training in Auto-Keras with StratifiedKFold

Tags: pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras, auto-keras

### Background

My sentiment analysis research comes across a variety of datasets. Recently I've encountered one dataset that somehow I just cannot train successfully. I mostly work with open data in `.CSV` file format, hence `Pandas` and `NumPy` are heavily used.

During my research, one of the approaches is trying to integrate automated machine learning (`AutoML`), and the library I chose to use was `Auto-Keras`, mainly using its `TextClassifier()` wrapper function to achieve `AutoML`.

### Main Problem

I've verified with official documentation, that the `TextClassifier()` takes data in the format of the NumPy array. However, when I load the data into `Pandas DataFrame` and used `.to_numpy()` on the columns that I need to train, the following error kept showing:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-1444bf2a605c> in <module>()
     16     clf = ak.TextClassifier(overwrite=True, max_trials=2)
     17 
---> 18     clf.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, callbacks=cbs)
     19 
     20 

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float).
```

### Error-related code sectors

The sector where I drop the unneeded `Pandas DataFrame` columns using `.drop()`, and convert the needed columns to `NumPy` Array using the `to_numpy()` function that `Pandas` has provided.

```py
df_src = pd.read_csv(get_data)

df_src = df_src.drop(columns=["Name", "Cast", "Plot", "Direction",
                "Soundtrack", "Acting", "Cinematography"])

df_src = df_src.reset_index(drop=True)

X = df_src["Review"].to_numpy()

Y = df_src["Overall Sentiment"].to_numpy()

print(X, "\n")
print("\n", Y)
```

The **main** error code part, where I perform `StratifedKFold()` and at the same time, use `TextClassifier()` to train and test the model.

```py
fold = 0
for train, test in skf.split(X, Y):
    fold += 1
    print(f"Fold #{fold}\n")
    
    x_train = X[train]
    y_train = Y[train]
    
    x_test = X[test]
    y_test = Y[test]
    
    
    cbs = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=3)]
    
    clf = ak.TextClassifier(overwrite=True, max_trials=2)
    
    
    # The line where it indicated the error.
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, callbacks=cbs)
    
    
    pred = clf.predict(x_test) # result data type is in lists of `string`
    
    ceval = clf.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
    
    metrics_test = metrics.classification_report(y_test, np.array(list(pred), dtype=int))
    
    print(metrics_test, "\n")
    
    print(f"Fold #{fold} finished\n")
```

### Supplementary

I am sharing the full code related to the error through `Google Colab`, which you can help me [diagnose here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1w11j4ep2yImMJvWqs7plFfcrX600f8r8?usp=sharing).

#### Edit notes

I have tried the potential solution, such as:

```py
x_train = np.asarray(x_train).astype(np.float32)
y_train = np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32)
```

or

```py
x_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,))
y_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((y_train,))
```

However, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the strings is equal to `nan`. Just remove this entry and the corresponding label.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to investigate. Now I can move on to handle the imbalanced label of this data.